# generated a rsa key with keytool - where is it?

Tags: security, rsa, keytool

I created a RSA key pair using keytool, but I need to get the public key.
I've read all around but can't find this information anywhere.

Is there a way to get that information? Or even where are the files located in windows 7?

Any suggestion will help..

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is stored under your user directory.

If you're on Windows it's under Users/ragalante/.keystore.